# Using purrr for rowwise operations

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm looking to use purrr for a rowwise operation where each element is used in the function as a string. The error I'm getting is that it can't attribute an $ to an atomic vector. Here's an example:

```
test_function = function(dat_) {
  
  petal_width = dat_$Petal.Width
  sepal_width = dat_$Sepal.Width
  petal_length = dat_$Petal.Length
  sepal_length = dat_$Sepal.Length
  
  list(petal_length,sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_width) %>%
    bind_cols -> test
  
  return(test)
  
}

apply(iris, 1, test_function)
```

Comment: Where are you using `purrr`? Everything here appears to be `dplyr` and base R. (BTW: `apply(iris,1,...)` is converting all columns to `character`, likely not what you want/need.)

Comment: i'm looking to perform this with purrr. i'm not sure where to start.

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect the output to be. And `purrr` is a package with many functions, some of which might be useful in a row-wise situation.

Comment: this is a toy example. here, the output would recreate the original set. it would take each row, assign each of its columns, and then bind the new elements back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your expected output is but you can use `pmap` to perform row-wise operations. However, `pmap` passes each row as a vector and not as dataframe so `$` will not work. You can change the function to :

```
library(tidyverse)

test_function = function(dat_) {

  petal_width = dat_[['Petal.Width']]
  sepal_width = dat_[['Sepal.Width']]
  petal_length = dat_[['Petal.Length']]
  sepal_length = dat_[['Sepal.Length']]
  tibble(a = petal_length,b = sepal_length,
         c = sepal_width,d = petal_width) -> test
  return(test)
}
```

You can use `pmap` as :

```
iris %>% mutate(data = pmap(select(., matches('Sepal|Petal')), 
               ~test_function(c(...)))) -> tmp
```

Each row of data is a tibble with data from that row.

```
tmp$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
      a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   1.4   5.1   3.5   0.2
```